# Attribute with no value in .xhtml pages

Tags: angularjs, xhtml

In firefox, the localized html pages have to use xhtml, because localized variables are brought in as:

```
&blah.sub.name;
```

But an issue is, with frameworks like angular, we need to set attributes that don't have a value. Such as ngCsp:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app ng-csp>
...
...
</html>
```

However xhtml doesn't agree with this and it throws errors. During runtime we can set these attributes with no value no problem, with javascript. However is there a way to do this not on runtime?

Comment: Attributes with no values are the same as attributes with empty values, that is, `np-app=""`

Comment: Oo interesting thanks @MrLister!

Comment: In Firefox, if you look at the generated source by selecting all and "View Selection Source" from the right click menu, you will see that an attribute created without value gets rendered as value `""`. [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/53wde8qn/).

Comment: O you're right man thanks man!